# I am getting a filenotfound error in my website's code

Tags: python, flask

I am getting a filenotfound error in my website that I have made using the flask. This is the code for the route where I am getting the error:

```
@app.route('/upload-manga', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            pics = request.files
            name_characters = sample(ascii_letters+digits, 12)
            post_name = ''.join(name_characters) #creating a variable of random strings
            os.mkdir('static/'+post_name) #creatinb new directory
            f = open('static/'+post_name+'/'+'README.txt', 'w') #creating a readme file
            f.write('.')
            f.close()
            app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"] = os.path.join('yff','static', post_name) #declaring file location where the file needs to be uploaded
            mangaName = request.form['mangaName']
            if not pics:
                return render_template('message.html', messsage="No images have been uploaded. ")
            else:
                sorted_pics = sorted(pics.getlist('pic'), key=lambda x:int(x.filename.split('.')[0]))
                for pic in sorted_pics:
                    filename = secure_filename(pic.filename)
                    mimetype = pic.mimetype
                    pic.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], filename))
                    direc = os.path.join('yff', 'static', post_name)
                    name = '/' + filename
                    direc = os.path.join('yff','static', post_name)
                    # name = '/' + filename
                    image = Image(title=filename, 
                    mimetype=mimetype, 
                    img_location=direc,
                    post_name=post_name,
                    user_id = current_user.id,
                    manga_name = mangaName)
                    db.session.add(image)
                    db.session.commit()
                Post = Posts(user_id = current_user.id,
                    post_name = post_name,
                )
                db.session.add(Post)
                db.session.commit()
                return render_template('message.html', message='The images have been uploaded')
                
        else:
            return render_template('upload.html')
    else:
        flash('You need to log in to upload images on this website')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Basically, in this code, I am checking if the user posted images in the web page I made. If the user is posting images, I am creating a random string that is the name of the directory I want to create. Each post (a post can contain multiple images) has a unique directory associated with it and each of the images of that post are to be stored inside of that directory.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Mar 25 05:21:07 PM  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/hCJUoWT09QpE'
```

I was expecting a directory to be created and then the images to be added to that directory.

Comment: have you tried providing full path instead?

Comment: @greendino I have not tried that as I have hosted my website on render.com (the place where I am getting this error is also render.com) and I have not been able to find a way to get access to absolute paths or directories of the server where my website is hosted on.